# Cómo recorrer una tabla para averiguar el valor de un campo y si no es el último del seguimiento, borrar registros posteriores

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla que tiene los campos Id(PK), Id_Tarea, Id_Estado y Seguimiento

[image: Tabla 1]

La tarea (campo Id_Tarea) va cambiando de estado (Id_Estado), el cual se va quedando la traza en el campo "Seguimiento".
El problema que tengo es que después del estado "20" no se deberían insertar más cambios de estado para esa tarea (Id_Tarea), pero en algunos casos si se han insertado cambios de estado.
Necesito localizar estas filas que se insertan después del 20 y eliminarlas.
Utilizo SQL Server Management Studio
¿Podría ayudarme alguien?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que cualquier otra cosa, debes evitar que este problema continue ocurriendo. Esto lo puedes hacer mediante un trigger que se ejecute en cada INSERT o UPDATE.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TI_MiTabla ON MiTabla
FOR INSERT /*, UPDATE*/
AS
IF EXISTS( SELECT *
            FROM MiTabla t
            JOIN inserted i ON t.Id_Tarea = i.Id_Tarea
                            AND t.Id <> i.Id
            WHERE t.Id_Estado = 20)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'La tarea ya había alcanzado su estado final.';
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
GO
```

Después ya podemos buscar las filas que deben ser removidas porque no cumplen la regla. Estoy asumiendo que Id es un campo que se incrementa constantemente y que es la única forma de identificar el orden de las filas.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MiTabla t
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * 
            FROM MiTabla i
            WHERE t.Id_Tarea = i.Id_Tarea
            AND t.Id > i.id
            AND i.Id_Estado = 20);
```

Una vez confirmando que esto regresa el resultado correcto, sólo hay que transformar el SELECT en un DELETE. Recuerda tener un respaldo de la información en caso de que haya que recuperarla.

```
--SELECT * 
DELETE
FROM MiTabla t
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * 
            FROM MiTabla i
            WHERE t.Id_Tarea = i.Id_Tarea
            AND t.Id > i.id
            AND i.Id_Estado = 20);
```